# How can I use OmegaConf custom interpolation with Hydra

Tags: fb-hydra

How can I use OmegaConf [custom interpolation](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#custom-interpolations) with [Hydra](https://hydra.cc)?

Some background:
One can define a custom interpolation for square root:

```python3
from omegaconf import OmegaConf
import math
OmegaConf.register_resolver("sqrt", lambda x: math.sqrt(float(x)))
```

And use it with this config.yaml:

```yaml
foo: ${sqrt:9}
```

Loading and printing foo:

```python
cfg = OmegaConf.load('config.yaml')
print(cfg.foo)
```

Outputs `3.0`

When trying this with Hydra:

```python
import hydra

@hydra.main(config_path="config.yaml")
def main(cfg):
  print(cfg.foo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

I get the following error:

```
Unsupported interpolation type sqrt
    full_key: foo
    reference_type=Optional[Dict[Any, Any]]
    object_type=dict
```

How can I register my resolver when using Hydra?

Answer (score 11):

You can register your custom resolver ahead of time:

config.yaml:

```yaml
foo: ${sqrt:9}
```

main.py:

```python
from omegaconf import OmegaConf
import math
import hydra

OmegaConf.register_new_resolver("sqrt", lambda x: math.sqrt(float(x)))

@hydra.main(config_path=".", config_name="config")
def main(cfg):
  print(cfg.foo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

This will print 3.0.

This approach will work just as well with the [Compose API](https://hydra.cc/docs/experimental/compose_api/). The evaluation of the custom resolver is happening when you access the node (lazily).
You just need to register the resolver before you access it.